# how to call controller from ajax request in spring mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/saveWorkingHours",
        data : "campaignWorkingHours="+JSON.stringify(campaignWorkingHours),
        async: false,    
        cache: false,              
        success : function(response) {

            $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jobSchedule"
                });

        }, 
        error : function() {
            alert("error");
        }
});
```

I have following controller method :

```
// For handling job schedule page request
@RequestMapping(value = "jobSchedule", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView jobSchedule() {

    ModelAndView workingHoursModel = new ModelAndView(
            Constants.CAMPAIGNWORKINGHOURS);

    try {

        // Get campaigns
        List<Object[]> lstCampaigns = CommonUtil.castList(Object[].class,
                objCommonService.getCampaigns());

        workingHoursModel.addObject("Campaigns", lstCampaigns);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return workingHoursModel;
}
```

got response in success from saveWorkingHours method of controller but job schedule method is not getting excuted.gettong following error:

> GET http://localhost:8081/CampaignDesigner/jobSchedule    0ms jquery-....min.js (line 4)
>   "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://localhost:8081/CampaignDesigner/jobSchedule"

Comment: Your `type` should be set to `GET` or your controller method should be configured to allow `POST` but both must agree or you get 405 errors.  Perhaps it is not routing to the method you indicated in your question?  Verify your controllers are registering properly; you can also double-check with Fiddler directly, or use the browser dev tools to review what's actually going on in XHR-ville.

Comment: saveWorkingHours method is configured to allow post so I have mentioned type as post in outer AJAX call but for the inner method type has to be GET

Comment: that may be but error 405 means what it means, so if the XHR request is going out correctly, then it's in the controller routing, because the service is saying Method Not Allowed, in spite of your assumptions.  you should also check the browser dev tools and get proof the XHR is going as you assume.